# How do i make my core java program browser based?

Tags: java, browser, jvm, webserver

[link1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43476/simulation-of-an-ocean-containing-sharks-and-fish) is my non-object oriented version of simulation program.

[link2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43921/suggestions-needed-after-modification-of-simulation-of-an-ocean) is an object oriented version of simulation(modified version of link1).

One of the file(simtext.java) in this program produces output on stdout by taking 3 command line arguments. Currently this program is built on eclipse, compiled/interpreted using java 7 tools.

Going further, For a single user, I want capability of giving 3 inputs on browser and see the output on browser rather than stdout/stdin respectively.

What are the elements that am suppose to think of as an approach to make it browser based?

I know this is very basic question, but am new to browser world.

Comment: This program should work for any browser available in the market. Currently i only have idea on Java/C. I am open to learn any other language/concept which is required for this requirement and should be a bestfit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you get a Web container such as Tomcat and then you create an HTML page with a form that submits to a Java Servlet that you create. You can get a lot fancier with JSPs or JSF but a plain Servlet based application should get you started.

Comment: w3c.org says HTML and CSS are the fundamental technologies for building Web pages. so i guess, i can read input and display output using html(ok i will learn this). where does my code logic run? how does html pass on given input to my back-end program? Does tomcat/servlet help me here? i dont want to be fancy here(i need minimum)

Comment: Tomcat is a web server. You create a HTML file that has a <form> that functions at the input. When users press the submit button the filled out form data is sent to the Servlet subclass that you created and installed in Tomcat. That servlet subclass parses the form data and returns HTML (or asks a JSP file to return the HTML)>

Comment: Assuming linux environment, If the server is 'tomcat webserver', and client is html? If yes, then html would run the socket api socket() and connect() and tomcat webserver will run socket api socket()/bind()/listen() & then accept() the data for every write() that client does. the data sent in each write() call would be http protocol based. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Reason am asking this point in my previous update is, where is servlet(subclass) fitting here with tomcat server amidst it's socket api socket()/bind()/listen() & then accept() the connection and read() the  data from client? For every write() call from client, Do i need to create a servlet on server side? If am clear on this part, I can think of how to use servlet for different core java programs. Am sure jvm internally uses socket api's some how in one or  other form.

Comment: Can somebody respond to to this query?

Comment: HTML doesn't run anything, it is a text format. The client is a web browser, the server is Tomcat. The client makes a socket connection to the server and using HTTP the client will make requests and the server will make responses. Responses will commonly contain HTML. Tomcat will handle all the ServerSocket accept/listen stuff for you. You might customize the server socket behavior by modify XML config files. A Servlet class that you create functions as a plug-in to Tomcat that allows you to customize the actions that take place when Tomcat receives a request.

Comment: Chase, Say if i  do not add a plugin(servlet class) at server side, and the client(browser) sends the input of 3 paramters to tomcat server, what does the  server reply?can we chat further on this? to avoid delay? another point is, Looks like 'tomcat webserver' allowed programmers to customise the actions on every request sent by client via servlet class, is that correct?

Comment: Chase, the meaning of 'servlet class that we create functions as a plugin to tomat', you mean, for every write() call that client does tomcat server accept() gets unblocked and forwards the data to my 'servlet class', is that true? and in reply servlet class can send back reply to client by running write() call internally, is that true? so we can design only one 'servlet class which has my program logic' per each listen socket of tomcat server?

Comment: i understand socket has clientipport&serveripport identity for each listen socket, but how does tomcat server differentiate which request belongs to which 'servlet class'  after accept() get unblocked on server side, ?

Comment: The browser sends an HTTP request to a specific URL (say GET host.com/page1). You have to set your servlet to be "page1". You do this with either an annotation in the servlet (more modern) or with a web.xml configuration file that you supply with your servlet. In most cases Tomcat reads in all of the HTTP request and converts it into an object called an HttpServletRequest. That object is then passed in to your servlet by Tomcat via a method call.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49687/discussion-between-user3317808-and-chase)

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [web development frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework) like [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home), which take care of the most frequent programming tasks if you want to deliver online. Usually there's great documentation and easy tutorials to get you started available and your output will actually look nice.

There're a lot of those frameworks out there, so if you have trouble choosing you could look at a [comparison](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/the-2014-decision-makers-guide-to-java-web-frameworks/).

Comment: Do i need to think of these many different frameworks to just make my core java application browser based? I think their is lot of stuff there. what is enough for my requirement, How do i know that? That will give me a good start to get oriented with web based frameworks. I am trying to learn web based technologies through some simple programs incrementally.